# Difference between Emend and Amend

Tags: meaning, verbs, differences

What's the difference between the verbs to *emend* and to *amend*? They both have the same definition on Oxford Online Dictionary as follows:

[emend](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/emend):

> Make corrections and revisions to (a text): '*these studies show him
>   collating manuscripts and emending texts*'

[amend](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/amend):

> Make minor changes to (a text, piece of legislation, etc.) in order to
>   make it fairer or more accurate, or to reflect changing circumstances:
>   '*the rule was amended to apply only to non-members*'

Comment: `emend` comes directly form lat `emendare`, while `amend` took the detour lat emendare > OF amender > ME amenden

Answer (score 7):

JoseK is correct that the meaning of *emend* is confined to textual alterations, and that *amend* can be broadened to include the general improvement of other things. Still, *amend* is mostly used in the sense of improving text. If you're talking about fixing a rip in a shirt, you would be better to just use the word *mend*; to *amend* the shirt would sound strange. The Constitution of the U.S. may be amended (as it has been) but if the actual document itself were damaged and required restoration I don't think anyone would say the team that did the work *amended* the Constitution.

Answer (score 3):

Both have a sense of "*improve* ***by adding to***", but *emend* is used generally for editing, as of a text, while you can amend many things.

Also, an *amendment* will generally come at the end of the original, but an *emendment* can occur anywhere in the text.

Answer (score 2):

*emend* seems to be used in the context of editing (specifically of some text)

while *amend* could be correcting or repairing or improving of anything.

Answer (score 1):

The statement that "They [*amend* and *emend*] have the same definition" is incomplete at best and misleadingly untrue at worse. A look at the entries for the two words in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) reveals that *amend* and *emend* have one definition in common, but that *amend* has a number of additional meanings that *emend* does not:

> **amend** *vb* {M[iddle] E[nglish], fr[om] A[nglo-]F[rench] *amender*, modif[ication] of L[atin] *emendare*, fr[om] *e*, *ex* out + *menda* fault; akin to L[atin] *mendax* lying, *mendicus* beggar, and perh[aps] to S[ansk[ri]t *mindā* physical defect} *vt* (13[th] c[entury]) **1 :** to put right; *esp* : to make emendations in (as a text) **2 a :** to change or modify for the better : IMPROVE {*amend* the situation} **b :** to alter esp. in phraseology; *esp* : to alter formally by modification, deletion, or addition {*amend* a constitution} ~ *vi* to reform oneself
>
> ...
>
> **emend** *vt* {M[iddle] E[nglish] fr[om] L[atin] *emendare* — more at AMEND} (15[th] c[entury]) : to correct usu. by textual alterations {*emended* the manuscript}

So, according to Merriam-Webster, both *amend* and *emend* can mean to introduce corrections into a text—but *amend* can also mean (as a transitive verb} in a more general sense to improve, or to alter the sense or provisions of (whether for good or for bad), and (as an intransitive verb) to reform oneself. *Emend* is not normally used in these last three senses.

Two other reference works confirm the central distinction that MW points out between *amend* (= "improve") and *emend* (= "correct"). From Harry Shaw, *Dictionary of Problem Words and Expressions* (1975):

> **amend, emend.** *Amend* means "to put right," "to change for the better." We *amend* by adding or altering, as the noun *amendment* suggests. *Emend*, once merely another spelling of amend, has a similar meaning but is properly used only to refer to corrections or changes made in a literary or scholarly work; the corresponding noun is *emendation*. Both *amend* and *emend* are verbs; *amend* in plural form (*amends*) becomes a noun meaning "recompense" or "compensation": "He made *amends* for his careless driving."

And from Adrian Room, *The Penguin Dictionary of Confusibles* (1979):

> **amend/emend** (change, alter)
>
> To 'amend' something is to improve it. A bill 'amended' in Parliament is thus altered for the better. The very common verb 'mend' is in fact derived from it, with the improving sense still clear in such an expression as 'mending' one's ways. To 'emend' something, on the other hand, is to correct it, remove the errors from it. The word is most often used with reference to a text of some kind that has been corrected. The noun of 'amend' is 'amendment'; of 'emend' it is 'emendation'.

Not to spoil the civics lesson, but a bit of thought about how the real world of politics operates should suffice to convince anyone that *amend* is often used in connection with making alterations to laws that do not improve them. For example, if the Eighteenth Amendment of the U.S. Constitution—the amendment prohibiting "the manufacture, sale, or transportation of intoxicating liquors" within, into, or out of the United States—improved that document, it's rather difficult to explain how the Twenty-first Amendment—the amendment repealing the Eighteenth Amendment—improved the same document. In the real world, laws are frequently amended into worse forms than they had before; the only accurate meaning *amend* has under those circumstances is "alter."

One example of the broader reach of *amend* in the sense of "improve" is its use (in U.S. English) in connection with adding nutrients or soil of contrasting characteristics to existing soil: Gardeners can amend the soil in their garden; they cannot emend it. As the various sources cited above indicate, *emend* refers primarily to editorial correction of textual errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've only ever encountered the word 'emend' in terms of Biblical criticism. There it's used to refer to textual changes that tweak a word or letter to give an alternative reading which makes more sense in context, assuming that the traditional word has been inadvertently altered over generations of copying.

Answer (score 0):

[OED's entry on *amend, v.*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/6300#eid5513197) states that 'emend' anteceded 'amend':

> Etymology:  < Old French amende-r
>   < Latin *ēmendā-re*   to free from fault, correct, improve,
>   < ē = *ex*  out    +    *mend-um* , *mend-a*  fault.
>   **The change from *e-* to *a-* took place very early**, being found in Provençal and Italian as well as Old French.
>    Already in 14th cent. aphetized [[Definition here]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aphesis) to [mend v](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/116389#eid37241684).

Also, the larger number of entries in OED's Webpage on *amend* (than its Webpage on *emend*) evidences the answers above, which emphasise the broadness of *amend* over *emend*.

Answer (score 0):

The use of EMEND suggests to correct, to facilitate a more accurate change, as opposed to AMEND that does not necessarily correct but modifies and or amplifies the intent.